# Sum operation not giving expected results without appropriate bracket placement?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

When I do a sum operation on some objects I have, they don't return the expected result and instead miss the last item in the list.

Here's the models used:

```
public class Item
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public List<ItemOption> Options { get; set; }
}

public class ItemOption
{
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
}
```

So when I do a sum operation like so it gives incorrect results, missing the last item...

```
items.Sum(x => x.Price + x.Options?.Sum(c => c.Price) ?? 0);
```

But when I do it with brackets like this, it works...

```
Console.WriteLine(items.Sum(x => x.Price + (x.Options?.Sum(c => c.Price) ?? 0)));
```

Any idea why adding brackets here would make it work as expected?

Here's something I've tried, first write line returns £16.80 and 2nd write line returns £10.20

```
var items = new List<Item>
{
new Item
{
    Price = 4.20M,
    Options = new List<ItemOption>
    {
        new ItemOption
        {
            Price = null
        }
    }
},
new Item
{
    Price = 6.00M,
    Options = new List<ItemOption>
    {
        new ItemOption
        {
            Price = null
        }
    }
},
new Item
{
    Price = 1.30M
},
   new Item
{
    Price = 5.30M
}

};


Console.WriteLine(items.Sum(x => x.Price + (x.Options?.Sum(c => 
c.Price) ?? 0)));
Console.WriteLine(items.Sum(x => x.Price + x.Options?.Sum(c => 
c.Price) ?? 0));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "missing the last item"? It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve]. Basically this is a precedence issue, but it's a lot easier to explain it if you can give a concrete example of the input, along with the result you expected vs the result you got.

Comment: [C# operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence)?

Comment: Have updated question with example in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens due to [C# operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence), addition has higher precedence then null-coalescing operator, so in the first case if `x.Options` is null `x.Price + x.Options?.Sum(c => c.Price) ?? 0` is evaluated as:

```cs
(x.Price + (decimal?)null) ?? 0
```

Which is evaluated as:

```cs
null ?? 0
```

Due to [lifted operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#lifted-operators) rules:

> The predefined unary and binary operators or any overloaded operators that are supported by a value type `T` are also supported by the corresponding nullable value type `T?`. These operators, also known as lifted operators, **produce null if one or both operands are null**; otherwise, the operator uses the contained values of its operands to calculate the result. For example:

```cs
int? a = 10;
int? b = null;
int? c = 10;

a++;        // a is 11
a = a * c;  // a is 110
a = a + b;  // a is null
```